# Valores por defecto de parámetros de funciones, que son funciones o constantes de una biblioteca de tercera parte

Tags: opencv, uml

Estoy creando varios diagramas de clases UML. En algunos de ellos, hay funciones miembro, cuyos parámetros son de tipos de datos definidos en bibliotecas de tercera parte, a saber, `cv::Mat`, `cv::Point`, entre otros, de la biblioteca OpenCV.

Varios de esos parámetros de funciones tienen valores por defecto, los cuales son también (en muchos casos) rutinas o constantes de la biblioteca OpenCV (como `cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_RECT, cv::Size(3,3))`, o `cv::BORDER_CONSTANT`)

Mis dudas al respecto son:

¿Debo especificar tales valores por defecto en mis diagramas de clases UML?, ¿es conveniente (en especial, en caso de las rutinas OpenCV)?

Dado el caso, ¿Cómo lo hago?